# Why the breakpoint is not hitting in client side in visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2008 and try to debug my code using Google Chrome.
When I setup breakpoints in .aspx.cs file then it is working correctly but in .aspx file it is not hitting.
Why?

Comment: add `dubugger;` in your Javascript code.

Comment: Added , still not working @RahulSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working only on IE

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    debugger;
    your function()
       {
         }
   </script>
```

but in Other browser you have to use Inspect Element by clicking F12 button ->source->page

I hope this will help u !!!!